# scipy.optimize,fmin makes multiple identical calls

Tags: python, scipy, minimum

I have noticed unusual behaviour of `scipy.optimize.fmin` function. I have something like this:

```
def func(phi):
    """ I'm looking for minimum value of this function """
    ....
    return value

fmin(func, [0], disp=0, full_output=1, retall=1)
```

While looking for minimum, function `fmin` made consecutive calls with the same parameter value 10 times. This is a list of parameters reported by `func`:

```
[0.0, 0.00025, 0.0005, 0.00075, 0.00125, 0.00175, 0.00275, 0.00375, 0.00575, 0.00775, 0.01175, 0.01575, 0.02375, 0.03175, 0.04775, 0.06375, 0.09575, 0.12775, 0.19175,
0.25575, 0.25575, <- consecutive calls here
0.31975, 0.31975, <- consecutive calls here
0.28775, 0.22375,
0.27175, 0.27175, <- consecutive calls here
0.23975,
0.26375, 0.26375, <- consecutive calls here
0.24775,
0.25975, 0.25975, <- consecutive calls here
0.25175,
0.25775, 0.25775, <- consecutive calls here
0.25375,
0.25675, 0.25675, <- consecutive calls here
0.25475,
0.25625, 0.25625, <- consecutive calls here
0.25525,
0.2555, 0.256, 0.2555,
0.255875, 0.255875, <- consecutive calls here
0.255625,
0.2558125, 0.2558125] <- consecutive calls here
```

Why would it do such thing? Is this simply a matter of not optimizing `scipy.optimize.fmin` (in which case, oh the irony), or is there a purpose for this behaviour? Currently, due to `func` being computationally expensive, I was forced to write a caching system to work around large number of redundant calls to it.

Comment: It's hard to understand how you generate the output you show.

Comment: @cel I had func print out phi values and formatted the list to show consecutive calls together

Comment: I won't be able to tell you what's going on, without seeing the function in action. If your function call is very expensive, adding function call caching will have negligible overhead even if every call is a cache miss. If you are using python3 [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) will give you caching with only 2 extra lines of code.

Comment: The venerable 'Numerical Recipes in C' 2nd edition has this to say: "The _downhill simplex method_ [...] is not very efficient in terms of the number of function evaluations that it requires. Powell's method is almost surely faster in all likely applications. However the downhill simplex method may frequently be the _best_ method to use if the figure of merit is "get something working quickly" for a problem whose computational burden is small." Now, why is it repeating calls? Well, it may just seem like it from your formatted output.Try Powell's (fmin_powell) minimization.